# apply function on numpy array on specified axis python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an `np` array,

```
>>>d
>>>array(
        [
            array([[  87,  594,  907],[ 976,  635, 192],[   3,  580,  115]], dtype=int32),
            array([[   0,  148, 1]], dtype=int32),
            array(),
            array(),
            ...,
            ...,
        ], dtype=object
)

def a(matrix):
    output = []
    for i in matrix: 
        if i[0]+i[-1] > 100:
            output.append(False)
        else:
            output.append(True)
    return output
```

the array `d` has many `matrix` which shape might change

I need to apply this function `a` on the array `d` only on the 1st axis,
to say, the `matrix` parameter first takes this array `array([[  87,  594,  907],[ 976,  635, 192],[   3,  580,  115]], dtype=int32)` and then `array([[   0,  148, 1]], dtype=int32)` and returns the output, How to do this in better way and without `for` loop

Comment: You might can use [apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) but do not expect much in your case if speed is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Daraan, that `apply` doesn't make sense here `d` is 1d, so it will just be `a(d)`.

Comment: The best you can do is `[a(i) for i in d].  `d` is 1d, and being object dtype basically a list.

Comment: ... or a fancy way `list(map(a,d))`